# Radix sort not sorting "some" numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I'm trying to implement `Radix sort`, from all i learnt is that it first compares the one's digit , places in the right order, the it goes for ten's so on and so fourth.

i tried to implement it but didn't got satisfactory results, what i'm doing wrong here?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct heap {
    int data;
};

int main()
{
    int arr[18] = {545, 934, 829, 883, 842, 957, 241, 856, 878, 101, 555, 20, 964, 529, 156, 161, 566, 820};
    int i;

    struct heap *heaparr = malloc(sizeof(struct heap) * 18);

    for(i=0; i<18; i++) {
        heaparr[i].data = arr[i];
    }

    int k = 0, temp, div = 1;
    int ind = 0;

    while(div<=100 ){
        k=0;
        ind = 0;
        while(k<10) {
            for(i=0; i<18; i++) {
                if ((heaparr[i].data/div)% 10 == k) {
                    temp = heaparr[ind].data;
                    heaparr[ind].data = heaparr[i].data;
                    heaparr[i].data = temp;
                    ind++;
                }
            }
            k = k+1;
        }
        div = div*10;
    }

    printf("\n");
    free(heaparr);
    return 0;
}
```

it is giving me result

```
20 101 156 161 241 545 555 566 529 842 856 820 829 878 883 957 934 964
```

ans it should be.

```
20 101 156 161 241 529 545 555 566 820 829 842 856 878 883 934 964 957
```

Comment: You should use `for (int div = 1; div <= 100; div *= 10)` instead of splitting the loop control over 3 lines in a `while` loop.  Similarly, use `for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)` rather than splitting the loop control over 3 lines in a `while` loop.  And please indent your code consistently — it really isn't that hard to do and it does make a tremendous difference to the readability.

Comment: The problem is that you don't keep the *other* that you swap away from the beginning, in order. Radix sort requires that the intermediate sorts are **stable**, yours is not.

Comment: thanks i'll keep that in mind 
@AnttiHaapala can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: Still can't figure out but I'll try again thanks

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter draw it on a paper.

Comment: Easiest to make it to work by sorting into another array. Or use a counting sort

Comment: Have you tried debugging for a small failing example?

Answer (score 3):

Radix sort requires the the intermediate sorts to be stable, as you can read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Definition). Here is a nice picture, explaining what stability is:

[image]

"An example of stable sort on playing cards. When the cards are sorted by rank with a stable sort, the two 5s must remain in the same order in the sorted output that they were originally in. When they are sorted with a non-stable sort, the 5s may end up in the opposite order in the sorted output."

---

So, in your code, when you are swapping two elements, you do not make sure that the stability is preserved for the element you take from the begining and are pushing back towards the end, which breaks the requirement of radix sort, thus producing undesired effects.

Inspired by [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/), I transformed your code to use [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (which is stable for the intermediate sorting steps):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>       /* pow */

struct heap {
    int data;
};

void print(struct heap* heaparr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        printf("%d ", heaparr[i].data);
    printf("\n");

}

// A function to do counting sort of arr[] according to
// the digit represented by exp.
struct heap* countSort(struct heap* heaparr, int n, int exp)
{
    int output[n]; // output array
    int i, count[10] = {0};

    // Store count of occurrences in count[]
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[ (heaparr[i].data/exp)%10 ]++;

    // Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual
    //  position of this digit in output[]
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    // Build the output array
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[ (heaparr[i].data/exp)%10 ] - 1] = heaparr[i].data;
        count[ (heaparr[i].data/exp)%10 ]--;
    }

    // Copy the output array to arr[], so that arr[] now
    // contains sorted numbers according to current digit
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        heaparr[i].data = output[i];
    return heaparr;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[18] = {545, 934, 829, 883, 842, 957, 241, 856, 878, 101, 555, 20, 964, 529, 156, 161, 566, 820};
    int i;

    struct heap *heaparr = malloc(sizeof(struct heap) * 18);

    for(i=0; i<18; i++) {
        heaparr[i].data = arr[i];
    }

    int k = 0, div = 1;

    while(div<=100 ){
        k=0;
        while(k<10) {
            for(i=0; i<18; i++) {
                countSort(heaparr, 18, (int)pow(10, heaparr[i].data/div% 10));
            }
            k = k+1;
        }
        div = div*10;
    }
    print(heaparr);
    free(heaparr);
    return 0;
}
```

which gives:

> 20 101 156 161 241 529 545 555 566 820 829 842 856 878 883 934 957 964

However, this should be just an example to get you started.

Comment: so i have precheck if the the 545 is not coming earlier than 529.

Comment: Sorry to mind you again, but wouldn't that increase the complexity?  like. If I'm transverseing again to check that what would be difference between radix and other O(n^2) complexity sorts, but somewhat I think this might be a good approach. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I see your point @PaulNicolashunter, that's why I just used a stable sort in my example. You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

@gsamaras beat me to it, but here's a much smaller minimal example.

```
Start with:
  52, 93, 84, 54, 24
```

The entire pass in the `1s` place leaves the values in the same places.
Now look at the swap operations when processing the `10s` place:

```
10s, k=0
10s, k=1
10s, k=2
  24, 93, 84, 54, 52 //The first swap mis-orders the "50s"
   ^---------------^
10s, k=3
10s, k=4
10s, k=5
  24, 54, 84, 93, 52
       ^-------^
  24, 54, 52, 93, 84 //Hence they stay out-of-order when they're moved up
           ^-------^
10s, k=6
10s, k=7
10s, k=8
  24, 54, 52, 84, 93
               ^---^
10s, k=9
```

Consider shifting the elements right to make space, rather than swapping, or do the processing of each decimal place out-of-place (i.e., alternating between two buffers).

Comment: well you could even remove `93, 84`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: True.  I only saw that afterwards.  I left it because there is such a thing as "too minimal to be illustrative"

Comment: so i have to take an extra space to swap the numbers? 
pardon me, couldn't get the latter one.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think it's about the out-of-place version.  What I meant is this: right now, you swap entries so that you don't have to move the values around a lot.  You could achieve the same thing by scanning across `heaparr` and writing to a new `heaparr2` when doing the 1s place.  On the next pass for the 10s place, reverse their roles: scan across `heaparr2` and write to `heaparr`.  At the end, return the last one written, and free the other.

Comment: Thanks, but would that increase the complexity? I'll try it and give the feedback asap

Comment: There are a couple of senses for 'complexity'.  In the sense of "harder to write", that depends on whether you're more comfortable with `malloc` or with `memmove`.  In my experience, I mess up the indexing and length for `memmove` much more than I mess up swapping pointers.  There's another sense of complexity as 'computational complexity' or 'how much work does the computer have to do'.  In that sense, the pointer version is better because it avoids repeatedly moving large chunks of array elements.